# How to visualizing the result of features which be extracted by BorutaPy(the Boruta algorithm realized by python)?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm extracting features using Boruta from my data. Now I have extracted 11 features using `BorutaPy(rf, n_estimators='auto', verbose=3, random_state=1).fit(X_std,y)`, but I don't know how to visualize the result?

What I used is:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, class_weight='balanced', max_depth=5)
feat_selector = BorutaPy(rf, n_estimators='auto', verbose=3, random_state=1)
feat_selector.fit(X_std, y)
feat_selector.support_
```

I get 11 features from my data. But I want to visualize the result like the `plot(Boruta.mydata)` using R. I don't know how to realize it using python.

The picture below shows the result I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently also came across this issue - where Python wouldn’t plot a Boruta graph. 
I ended up using R to finish it and exported the important features back to Python

Comment: Welcome to SO! That is rather a comment than an answer. Wait to win some Rep to do it. Some OP will vote it down.